# Cambiar color del texto al dar scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Tengo un menú que al bajar la página, éste continúa ahí y el color cambia de transparente a blanco, pero la letra deseo que cambie a negro.

Tengo en mi código JS que tome el identificador del div padre y cambie a todos sus hijos el color. Pues no me funciona, ya he intentado de varias formas y aun no he dado con el clavo.

Pongo mi código ([también en JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ciscojuan/t3x6cvpm/10/)):

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction()
};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.height = "75px";
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.color = "#000";
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.line - height;
    "37.5px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.height = "100px";
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.color = "#000";
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.line - height;
    "50px";
  }
}
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
}

#cabecera {
  width: 100%;
  height: 755px;
}

#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: 0.4s;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 99;
}

#navbar .container {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#navbar #title {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: inherit;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 30%;
}

#navbar .container .menu {
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: inherit;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#navbar .container .menu>a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="cabecera" style="background-image: url(img/bg_3.jpg);background-size: cover;">
  <div id="navbar">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="index.html" id="title"><b id="b">JORGE ACEVEDO </b></a>
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="#cabecera"><b id="b">Jorge Acevedo</b></a>
        <a href="#cuerpo"><b id="b">Mis Propuestas</b></a>
        <a href="#suscribe"><b id="b">Contacto</b></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esto es un problema con la precedencia de los selectores y la herencia de valores en CSS.

Le estás cambiando el color al texto del elemento con id `navbar`, pero en el CSS tienes declarado que el color de los `a` será blanco. Entonces no importa que le cambies el color al `navbar` con JavaScript, porque los `a` dentro del `navbar` tienen su propio color en el CSS.

Una solución rápida sería:

- Ponerle a los `a` un valor de color igual a `inherit`, de este modo heredará el color del padre/ancestro que lo tenga definido.

  ```
  a {
    color: inherit;
    ...
  }
  ```
- Ponerle al `navbar` el blanco como color inicial.

  ```
  #navbar {
    color: white;
    ...
  }
  ```

Aquí puedes ver tu código con esos dos cambios:

> Nota: he corregido un pequeño bug (el color nunca se ponía como blanco al hacer scroll hacia arriba) porque estaba relacionado con la pregunta, pero he dejado sin tocar otra parte del código que contiene errores (`height` no está definido) porque no están relacionados con el problema de la pregunta.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction()
};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.height = "75px";
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.color = "#000";
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.line - height;
    "37.5px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.height = "100px";
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.color = "#fff";
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.line - height;
    "50px";
  }
}
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  color: inherit;
}

#cabecera {
  width: 100%;
  height: 755px;
}

#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: 0.4s;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 99;
  color: white;
}

#navbar .container {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#navbar #title {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: inherit;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 30%;
}

#navbar .container .menu {
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: inherit;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#navbar .container .menu>a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="cabecera" style="background-image: url(img/bg_3.jpg);background-size: cover;">
  <div id="navbar">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="index.html" id="title"><b id="b">JORGE ACEVEDO </b></a>
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="#cabecera"><b id="b">Jorge Acevedo</b></a>
        <a href="#cuerpo"><b id="b">Mis Propuestas</b></a>
        <a href="#suscribe"><b id="b">Contacto</b></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfecto!. Gracias por darme una leccion de prelacion en los selectores xD

Comment: tu post me ayudo mucho, pero tengo la duda si yo quiero cambiar el logo mediante el js, cual seria la línea de código